# How to create self-contained borders in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I have

```
<div id="aboutPyKov">
        <h2 id="pyKovSubheading">About PyKov</h2>
        <p id="pyKovIs">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,<br/>consectetur 
            adipiscing elit.<br/>Vestibulum congue mattis odio.<br/>Nulla f 
            acilisi. Quisque tempus<br/>varius enim, quis mattis metus, 
            <br/>auctor quis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br/>amet, consectetur 
            adipiscing elit.<br/>Pellentesque a euismod sem, a<br/>convallis 
            turpis. Donec aliquet<br/>quis leo at fermentum. Maecenas<br/>ut
            lacinia magna. Maecenas gravida<br/>interdum turpis non 
            fermentum.</p>                                              
</div>
```

For styling, I have

```
#aboutPyKov {
    border: 8px dotted rgba(255,198,107,0.93);
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

This works fine, however it shows a dotted border around the whole width of the whole page. I want it to be self-contained, but instead, it goes around the whole screen as you can see in [image] this picture. How do I make it so it only goes around the text? Also, the top border is hugging the background color above it. I would also like to know how to change that.

Comment: share html code

Comment: inside the question

Comment: i just did @TemaniAfif

Comment: Add `display:inline-block`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is CSS level *1*: block and inline. Block elements take up 100% of available `width` unless you set them to `float` or set an explicit `width`. Either set the `border` to the paragraph element or set a `width` to your `div`.

Comment: @EagleGaming ...and has less than ideal engine coverage. Don't jump to immediately start using stuff before you know *all* of your options, most especially if you don't know version 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `padding = 0px"` to your `<p>` tag and `<h2>` tag,

```
p, h2 {
padding: 0px;
}
```

because `<p>` and `<h2>` tags have default padding applied.

Answer (score 0):

## Just change the display attribute

```
#aboutPyKov {
    border: 8px dotted rgba(255,198,107,0.93);
    border-radius: 20px;
    display:inline-block; // just change the display
}
```